# Cropped UIImage Orientation / Stretching

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, crop

I have an app that includes a profile picture for the user. After the user selects the photo they want, it is automatically cropped using the following basic UIImage extension:

```
func crop() -> UIImage {

    let imageRef:CGImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.CGImage, CGRectMake(0, self.size.height/2 - self.size.width/2, self.size.width, self.size.width))!
    let cropped:UIImage = UIImage(CGImage:imageRef)

    return cropped

}
```

It works properly for most photos, but for some reason sometimes it changes the orientation of the photo, and sometimes it stretches the photo. Below is a photo of each so you can see what I mean:

[image: Wrong Orientation]

[image: Stretching/Compressing]

I have read a lot of posts about wrong orientation and still don't understand what's wrong with my code above. Furthermore, I haven't seen anything about stretching/compressing of photos.

Does anyone has any idea of how I could fix these problems?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Photos you take with your phone have their `imageOrientation` property, which you should take into account when instantiating the `cropped` image. The stretch should be possible to fix with `UIImageView`'s `contentMode` property.

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
image.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
image.layer.masksToBounds = false
image.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.size.width/2
image.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: How am I supposed to use this in my extension?

Comment: take your image that you want it to be cropped in image(uiimage) then use this code